# In Web Application, can't find newly added WCF service method

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have added a new function in business layer and in my service layer I have added that service method also and call that BLL function. it builds successfully. In my test project I can see the method and can call that service function. but in Web Application, i can see all the other function except the new function.

in web application service reference i am doing the following:

- To update a service reference
- In Solution Explorer, right-click the service reference and then click Update Service Reference.
- A progress dialog box is displayed while the reference is updated from its original location, and the service client is regenerated to reflect any changes in the metadata.

But still can't get it. Is there any solution?

Comment: have you added it to the service interface?

Comment: Yes i have added in service interface. unit test project is calling that function. but Application can't find the function.

Comment: If you use svcutil does it generate the proxy.

Comment: And you decorated it with the OperationContract attribute?

Comment: I am new in WCF. don't know how to use svcutil.. can you tell me please. hi jonathan, yes i am using OperationContract.

Comment: Thanks guys.. It works now.. but no idea how it fixed... I just debug or release build few times....